# Facing DeadlineTimeoutException while using Apache HttpClient with Spring webclient

Tags: spring-webclient, apache-httpclient-5.x

I have setup WebClient with apache httpclient 5 connector. Here my code snippet

```
@Bean
public WebClient webClient() {
        HttpAsyncClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpAsyncClients.custom();
        final PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManager connManager = 
        PoolingAsyncClientConnectionManagerBuilder
                .create()
                .build();
        clientBuilder.setConnectionManager(connManager);
        CloseableHttpAsyncClient client = clientBuilder.build();
        ClientHttpConnector connector = new HttpComponentsClientHttpConnector(client);
        return WebClient.builder().clientConnector(connector).build();
    }
```

I did a loading test with my rest API which internally calls remote URL using WebClient configuration as mentioned above. I see many requests failed with error

```
Caused by: org.apache.hc.core5.util.DeadlineTimeoutException: Deadline: 2022-02-02T14:01:23.844+0530, -451 MILLISECONDS overdue
at org.apache.hc.core5.util.DeadlineTimeoutException.from(DeadlineTimeoutException.java:49)
at org.apache.hc.core5.pool.StrictConnPool.processPendingRequest(StrictConnPool.java:318)
at org.apache.hc.core5.pool.StrictConnPool.processNextPendingRequest(StrictConnPool.java:299)
```

I am not able to find what configuration should be added in order to fix the issue. Can anyone please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: That basically means the client has run of available connections or was unable to produce a connection within the given deadline. Run your code with connection management logging on to find out why.

Comment: How did you resolve it? I still didn't get it. I'm running Flink application on AWS Kinesis, I'm closing connection right in time, but after some time 12-24 hours it starts to fail with error above.

Comment: @GensaGames Sorry I tried to check whether it will work with the apacheclient but now were are not using it. So not sure how to resolve this